# .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter doesn't align

Tags: vba, ms-word

```
Do While Z <= partcount - 3
    With wordapp.Documents(worddoc).Tables(2)
        With .Cell(Z, 1)
            With .Range
                .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
                With .Font
                    .Size = 11
                    .Bold = False
                    .ColorIndex = 1
                    .Name = "Arial"
                End With
            End With
        End With
    End With
    Z = Z + 1
 Loop
```

the macro runs all the way through, but the cells do no get aligned to the center. all other formatting works...probably missing something super basic, always happens to me that way.

Comment: tip: you can reduce the number of code lines by using `With wordapp.Documents(worddoc).Tables(2).Cell(Z, 1).Range`

Answer (score 1):

figured it out.
because i'm creating an instance of word from excel (i neglected to include that in the question), the problem was word's predefined properties. new code:

```
Do While Z <= partcount + 1
    With wordapp.Documents(worddoc).Tables(2).Cell(Z, 1).Range
        .ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 1
        With .Font
            .Size = 11
            .Bold = False
            .ColorIndex = 1
            .Name = "Arial"
        End With
    End With
    Z = Z + 1
Loop
```

thank you!